# Itext7 jar not found

Tags: java, maven, itext, itext7

I would like use Itext7 but when I try to import the dependency with maven, jar is not found. And when I search on maven central :
[Maven central Itext7](https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.itextpdf%7Citext7-core%7C7.0.2%7Cpom)
I found item but there is not jar in this dependency
[Itext 7 repository](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/itextpdf/itext7-core/7.0.2/)

Comment: I found the solution : add <type>pom</type> to maven depency, this wil download all artifact from core dependency

Answer (score 5):

`iText7` is no longer a single jar. It has a lot of modules. `itext7-core` artifact is merely an ensemble of modules comprising `Core` product. It is not a jar per se, it just has a dependency on all modules that comprise `Core`.

If you want to download the jars manually, use the following links (for `7.0.2`):

- [io](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/itextpdf/io/7.0.2/)
- [kernel](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/itextpdf/kernel/7.0.2/)
- [layout](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/itextpdf/layout/7.0.2/)
- [pdfa](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/itextpdf/pdfa/7.0.2/)
- [sign](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/itextpdf/sign/7.0.2/)
- [barcodes](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/itextpdf/barcodes/7.0.2/)
- [forms](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/itextpdf/forms/7.0.2/)

You can also find how to reference those dependencies separately with Maven [here](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.itextpdf%22).

Answer (score 4):

`itext7-core-7.0.2` is POM-only, as you can see in the POM file. It's only purpose is to have the other jars as a dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Make explicit the type as 'pom'

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itext7-core</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.2</version>
    <type>pom</type> 
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above IText7 is now multiple jars which you can download as required.

The below particular link is useful as it mentions clearly which are DEFINITELY required and which are optional

[IText7 Download Links From ITextSite](https://developers.itextpdf.com/itext7/download-and-install-information/Java)

Answer (score 0):

Setting the type as 'pom' may help in simple projects.
But if you create a new Maven --> JavaFX Application,
and if you explicitly mark the dependency as 'pom', 
then any attempt to build the application FAILS with message:
"*Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:unpack-dependencies (unpack-dependencies) on project DemoItext7: Unknown archiver type: No such archiver: 'pom'. -> [Help 1]*"
For details see [demo](https://mega.nz/#!YHoTFSLL!JuuSQOL0g0WodEQCRMg_wVbcFNTKLjKL3FpQWZ0gsLM).